# Asinine message preventing me from installing Xcode on 10.9.4

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, install, xcode

Every time I try to install Xcode from within the Mac App Store, I get "Download for free? This item will be added to your Purchases and will be available even if your Family Sharing Status changes".

I click Download. Then I see a spinning wheel for a second until I get the same message again until I just press 'Cancel'. It never downloads.

[image]

Does anyone know what the deal is?

I'm on a fresh install of OS X 10.9. Only thing I've done to it is sign in to the Mac App Store using my New Zealand account. I also installed and updated Office 2011. So I certainly haven't done anything unusual to this Mac!

Comment: The only workaround that I know of is to download it from the developer center.

Comment: There is Family Sharing already in 10.9?

Comment: @Tetsujin Hi, actually I did Google around but I found nothing related to Xcode and this 'Family Sharing' message. I don't have a clear answer yet if there's something wrong with my Apple account, or it's a temporary problem experienced by everyone else. Try posting a link if you are going to claim my question has already been asked? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

App Store has a track record (with me at-least) of throwing, and I quote you, asinine messages at it's users. The only workaround that I know of is to download Xcode from the [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com).